# Is it possible to add the groupitem's itemcount in a separate label somewhere else on the same form?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am writing a new application that contains a DataGrid (c# WPF) and I have the itemcount displayed above the section and would like that count to show in a label also.  How would I do this ?

[link to the photo of the datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsScJ.png)

I have tried 
`<Label Width="30" Height="30" 
Content="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=Items.Count}" />`

but it shows the entire row count and not just the "installed" count.

```
    <Style x:Key="groupheaderstyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" Background="LightBlue" Foreground="Black">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                            </DockPanel>

                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>[Link to the datagrid photo][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situation like these having a look at the structure of your ItemsSource helps.

I guess this should do the trick.

```
// For first group
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ItemsSource.Groups[0].ItemCount, ElementName=dataGrid1}" />

// For second group
<Label Content="{Binding Path=ItemsSource.Groups[1].ItemCount, ElementName=dataGrid1}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this to work with your suggestions.